# weighted average of interest rate

Tags: average

Let say that I have 2 loans. One loan has an interest rate of 5% and the other of 10%. I calculate the weighted average both loans and it is 8% (This is an example). I don't know how can you prove that the total interest yield of both loans with thier original interest rates is the same as if both loans interest rate was 8%. I don't know how to prove it. I would like some intuition.

Comment: **How** do you calculate that the "weighted average of both loans" is 8^%?  The only way I know to find such a weighted average is use the fact that "the total interest yield of both loans with their original interest rates is the same as if both loans interest rate was 8%."  You don't need to prove it- that is the **definition** of "weighted average".

Comment: my confusion is for example, let say that loan 1 is a loan with a term of 60 month at 5% and that at the end the loan will yield 2000 in interest. Also Loan 2 is with term of 60 month at 7% and the loan will yield 2500. The balance of the loan does not matter my confusion y how can i be sure that using the weight average will yiled the same 4500 in interest. you know that the interest of a loan is not just multiplying the balance by the rate, there is an amortization process

Answer (score 0):

Set the interests equal to each other to figure the relative size of the loans.

$.08x + .08y = .05x + .10y$

$.03x = .02y$

$x = \frac{2}{3}y$

Therefore the $x$ loan is $\frac{2}{3}$ of the $y$ loan.

Example:

$x = 600; y = 900$

$.08x + .08y = .05x + .10y$

$.08(600) + .08(900) = .05(600) + .10(900)$

$48 + 72 = 30 + 90$

$120 = 120$